# Why Qt debug fails with OpenCV with VideoCapture an Writer (using ffmpeg) , while run works?

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, makefile, ffmpeg

Windows, MSVC 2013. When I run a program in QtCreator that uses OpenCV(2410)'s VideoCapture or VideoWriter, it works. When I debug it, it fails. It's just a test program from the OpenCV website. These functions call on ffmpeg library, but I can't see why it fails/runs in debug mode (there is no error message).

That is, the debug program uses .lib's while the run program uses dll's right?, but I run it with a Debug.Makefile then it works, I debug it with the same Debug.Makefile it fails.

in Project.PRO:

`INCLUDEPATH += "C:\Users\me\OPENCV2410\opencv\build\include`

`LIBS += -L$(OPENCV_LIB32) -lopencv_videostab2410d -lopencv_highgui2410d \ etc`

Can OpenCV programs that use these functions not be debugged at all? Should I build a .lib myself, would that work?

Comment: Was the debug ffmpeg library compiled with the same compiler that you are using? Are you using a debug binary in debug mode?

Comment: ffmpeg has only non-debug binaries as far as I can tell, these functions (VideoWriter and VideoCapture) are in a modul called highgui, when debugging I use the lib files with a d postfix (as in opencv_highgui2410d.lib), at least, that's what I think I'm doing

Comment: I figured it out, I used wrong tags in .pri